# How to Import[...] a datafile from a file created by OpenAppend[...]

Tags: code-review, code-request

I created a datafile as follows:

```
ESTgrowth = FileNameJoin[{"Filepath", "ESTgrowth"}];
open = OpenAppend[ESTgrowth];
Write[open, newdata];  (*"newdata" is a list of data appended to "ESTgrowth" *)
Close[open];
```

This `code` appends data stream as follows:

```
{-17.071, 137.567, 16.554, 0.65}
{-16.873, 136.138, 16.934, 0.7}
{-15.397, 135.738, 16.894, 0.7}
{-14.7, 135.982, 15.9, 0.6}
```

Then I tried to import the data file to present it using `TableForm[...]`.
Of course,

```
Import[ESTgrowth, "Table"]
```

would NOT work because the data stream consists of lists of data only. My question is how to automatically put the data stream into the following format:

```
{ 
  {-17.071, 137.567, 16.554, 0.65},
  {-16.873, 136.138, 16.934, 0.7},
  {-15.397, 135.738, 16.894, 0.7},
  {-14.7, 135.982, 15.9, 0.6}
}
```

for `TableForm[...]` to work as expected.

Screenshot of my dataset with Extra commas placed in fixed positions in each row.

[image]

Screenshot of NOT working code.

[image]

Comment: Maybe `{Import[...]}`?

Comment: Perhaps study the documentation for Read. Hidden behind Details and Options it claims it can read one Expression. So perhaps Read corresponds to Write in that each can do one Expression at a time. Try it on simple examples and see if you can make it work.

Comment: Looking at latest screen shot, you do not have an extra "\n" at the front. So you do not need the command `In[23356]`. Simply do not use that one. I added this since you said you had extra "\n" at the front. Which I also saw on my end when using V 11.3. But it looks like now you do not get that extra "\n".  So simply do not use that extra step we added. Try it again, but without step `In[23356]` where it drops first letter, and it should work.

Comment: @Nasser: I will try it again and let you know the result. I hope it will work...Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off removing the MMA formatting completely, and then relying on `ImportString`'s euristics:

```
text = Import["yourFile.dat", "Text"];
ImportString@StringReplace[text, {"{" -> "", "}" -> ""}]

(*Out:
{
 {-17.071`, 137.567`, 16.554`, 0.65`},
 {-16.873`, 136.138`, 16.934`, 0.7`},
 {-15.397`, 135.738`, 16.894`, 0.7`},
 {-14.7`, 135.982`, 15.9`, 0.6`}
} 
*)
```

Really, though, it would be best to plan ahead and write a more sensible format to file (say, a CSV?) in the first place.

Comment: Before importing my data, I should first export it in text format. I did it following @Nasser's code above and then added `ImportString@...` as you suggested. But it does not work but creates more problems.

Comment: @Tugrul I am not sure I understand. I assumed that you had a text file in which the data was presented as you indicated in your question, i.e. rows of expressions like `{a, b, c,...}`. So I copied the data you had in the question to a file, called it yourFile.dat, then used the code reported. What problems did that create?

Comment: No I did not have a `txt` file. Every time I do calculations, a list is generated and appended to a file. The subsequent calculations generate similar lists and they are also appended to the file. The file looks like this: {list1} {list2} ...{listn} in the form of multiplication. This is the file I like to import. @Nasser's answer solved my problem with a minor revision. Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

This works on V 12.1 on windows

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
open = OpenAppend["ESTgrowth.txt", FormatType -> InputForm];
Do[
  newdata = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, 4];
  Write[open, newdata],
  {n, 1, 3}
  ];
Close[open];
```

Now the file looks like this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To read it back, we must make a list of lists. This is done by replacing each "\n" with "," and adding "{" at start and adding "}" at end of the string. Only after that, we can convert it to Mathematica experssion.

```
dataBack = Import["ESTgrowth.txt"];
dataBack = StringReplace[dataBack, "\n" -> ","];
dataBack = StringInsert[dataBack, "{", 1];
dataBack = StringInsert[dataBack, "}", -1];
dataBack = ToExpression[dataBack]

(*    {{3, 9, 1, 2}, {8, 10, 10, 10}, {0, 2, 0, 5}}  *)
```

If we now run the above code all over again, it still works, and the file now looks like this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And data is read back OK as

```
  {{3, 9, 1, 2}, {8, 10, 10, 10}, {0, 2, 0, 5}, {0, 7, 5, 6}, {9, 8, 8, 
     8}, {8, 7, 8, 2}}
```

**Update**

For V 11.3, it has an extra "\n" at start of file. So for V 11.3 the following should work

```
open = OpenAppend["ESTgrowth.txt", FormatType -> InputForm];
Do[
  newdata = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, 4];
  Write[open, newdata],
  {n, 1, 3}
  ];
Close[open];
```

Now

```
dataBack = Import["ESTgrowth.txt"];
dataBack = StringReplace[dataBack, "\n" -> ","];

(*this line below only needed for V 11.3 *)
dataBack = StringDrop[dataBack, 1]; (*delete the extra "," we added*)

dataBack = StringInsert[dataBack, "{", 1];
dataBack = StringInsert[dataBack, "}", -1];
dataBack = ToExpression[dataBack]
```

Gives

```
 {{1, 8, 8, 7}, {0, 7, 8, 0}, {9, 10, 6, 6}}
```

**Update**

It looks like OP is till seeing an issue on V 11.3, but I am not able to duplicate it. Here are the steps again showing result of each step. On windows 10.

Here is showing step-by-step the above on V 11.3

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
open = OpenAppend["ESTgrowth.txt", FormatType -> InputForm];
Do[
  newdata = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, 4];
  Write[open, newdata],
  {n, 1, 3}
  ];
Close[open];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
dataBack = Import["ESTgrowth.txt"];
InputForm[dataBack]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
dataBack = StringReplace[dataBack, "\n" -> ","];
InputForm[dataBack]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
dataBack = StringDrop[dataBack, 1]; (*delete the extra "," we added*)
InputForm[dataBack]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
dataBack = StringInsert[dataBack, "{", 1];
InputForm[dataBack]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
dataBack = StringInsert[dataBack, "}", -1];
InputForm[dataBack]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
dataBack = ToExpression[dataBack];
InputForm[dataBack]
```

gives

```
 {{3, 3, 1, 2}, {9, 6, 7, 8}, {6, 1, 10, 6}}
```

Comment: My "newdata"  is not in the format you have above. My format does not have commas in between individual lists and also the first and the very last curly brackets. This was my problem in the first place.

Comment: @TugrulTemel `My format does not have commas in between individual lists` I do not know how this can be possible in Mathematica. You mean like this? `list ={ {1} {2}}` This becomes multiplication. You can't have list of lists without comma in Mathematica. And I just use the format you showed in your quesiton. But may be your work flow is different.

Comment: When I run the model, the output is a list of numbers. This list is saved to `ESTgrowth ` file by `OpenAppend[ESTgrowth]`. Each time I run the model, the generated list is appended to the `ESTgrowth` file. Therefore, the final version of `ESTgrowth` is just a list of lists stacked under each other. MMA does this.

Comment: @TugrulTemel I see. OK, will try to update the answer to reflect this. Just need little more time. Have to make some coeffee

Comment: Take your time. Looking forward to hearing from you...

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. It works "almost fine". There is a slight revision to be made in the resulting `databack`, which is to delete all `Null` strings that appear in the resulting file. I will try with `DeleteCases[...]` to delete Nulls from the databack. Thanks again for this.

Comment: Your code generates an extra "," when you replace `"\n"->","` but when I change it to `"\n"->"  "` then the lists is multiplied by itself. I think `StringReplace[...]` needs to be revised not to create an extra comma. I tried to delete Null replaced in place of comma but the problem is still there.

Comment: @TugrulTemel  I do not see any extra "," in the code I run as you can see. So I am not sure why you are seeing something different. The code I used is above. Feel free to try it. I am using V 12.1 on windows and see no issue. May be you are using different OS or version. I do not know.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to find a solution for this because my computer (MMA v13) is generating an extra comma and then Replaces `Null` string to the lists. When I try to remove the string `Null` then MMA multiplies the lists. With kind regards,

Comment: @TugrulTemel I just tried it on V 11.3 and I do see the difference. But easy to fix. Will post what to do in that case now.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have been trying to fix it but no success yet. Look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: @TugrulTemel added it. All what you needed to do is remove the extra "," at the start. V 11.3 adds "\n" at the start for some reason. This causes "," to show up at the start. So we just needed to remove it.

Comment: Sorry but it does not work because extra commas are seen in several places in a given list, not in the beginning of the lists. Instead of removing commas, I should remove "Null" expressions placed in place of the extra commas.

Comment: @TugrulTemel Then your data itself must be different that what I am using to test with. I'll post now a screen shot showing step by step what I did on V 11.3 and you can see for yourself it works for me. So something else must be different on your end.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Something is weird on my side. I will look forward to seeing your screenshots. I will then see where my data is different from yours.

Comment: I see your code does work fine in your end. I edited my question with a screenshot of the data created if I apply your code step by step. Maybe this is bug?

Comment: @TugrulTemel  But do you see any issue if you run the same code I posted? Exactly the same steps I did? Not using your data or anything else? If the code I posted works OK, then the problem is with the data itself your are using, which I have no access to.

Comment: If I use the exact code of yours without deleting the extra commas, it works as you indicated. I do not see any problem. However, when you delete extra commas, then it does not work. I put the screenshot of this not working steps.

Comment: I tried it again but no success. If you look at the data screenshot placed in the original message, there are Nulls (I circled in red line) due to extra commas. The data looks like a matrix but `Dimensions[]` gives `(5,1)` meaning that a list is read as one element. `Dimension` should give me `(5,42)`. Obviously, on my side something is wrong but I cannot find it. I think this problem is very difficult to solve due to some strange behavior on my computer. Maybe you should not spend much time on this problem. I really feel guilty. Thank you really for your help.

Comment: @TugrulTemel sorry it is not working for you. It works for me OK. I would really suggest to unaccept this answer since it does not do what you want, this way it will encourage someone else to make new answer which hopefully gives a solution which works for you.

Comment: Unaccepted...Thanks for all your efforts.